Facing Java Heap Space errors in driver Spark
I am trying to upgrade my spark application from 2.4.7 to 3.4.1.
While migrating, I faced issues related to OOM in driver, even after having majority of the config and instances same(running on EMR).
Logs are as follows:
in executor
24/04/22 12:03:26 ERROR YarnCoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Executor self-exiting due to : Driver ip-172-34-10-202.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:34233 disassociated! Shutting down.

in driver
Majorly, I am reading from kafka topic, and doing some transformations and writing onto s3 and snowflake. But the step usually breaks on simple transformations such as adding a new column, which earlier used to work fine in spark 2.4.7.
Configs:
Spark Version 3.4.1
EMR version: emr-6.15.0
Core Machine: c6g.xlarge
Configuration set through EMR:
[
    {
      "Classification": "spark",
      "Properties": {
        "maximizeResourceAllocation": "true"
      }
    },
    {
      "Classification": "capacity-scheduler",
      "Properties": {
        "yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator": "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator"
      }
    },
    {
      "Classification": "yarn-site",
      "Properties": {
        "yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled": "false",
        "yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled": "false",
        "yarn.node-labels.enabled": "true",
        "yarn.node-labels.am.default-node-label-expression": "CORE"
      },
      "Configurations": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "Classification": "spark-defaults",
      "Properties": {
        "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35",
        "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35",
        "spark.shuffle.compress": "true",
        "spark.shuffle.spill.compress": "true"
      },
      "Configurations": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "Classification": "spark-env",
      "Properties": {
        
      },
      "Configurations": [
        {
          "Classification": "export",
          "Properties": {
            "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"
          },
          "Configurations": [
            
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

Configurations set though Command
"--conf",
"spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/hadoop/log4j.properties",
"--conf",
"spark.task.maxFailures=8",
"--conf",
"spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=5",
"--conf",
"spark.streaming.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true",
"--conf",
"spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer",
"--conf",
"spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable=true",
"--conf",
"spark.scheduler.maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime=300s",
"--conf",
"spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout=600s",

Configurations set through code
"spark.driver.maxResultSize" = 0
"spark.executor.memory"= "18G"
"spark.executor.cores" = "5"
"spark.executor.memoryOverhead" = "1024"
"spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled"= "true"

I have tried increasing the driver memory to 20GB by mentioning spark.driver.memory as 20GB. Also changed the spark.driver.maxResultsSize to 0. But still facing the memory issues.
Also cant give it more memory, (not able to understand why it is breaking) as it is used to work fine with default 1GB with spark 2.4.7
